# cd to directory and su to particular user on remote server in script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ssh, command-line-interface

I have some tasks to do on a remote Ubuntu CLI-only server in our offices every 2 weeks. I usually type the commands one by one, but I am trying to find a way (write a script maybe?) to decrease the time I spend in repeating those first steps.

Here is what I do:

```
ssh my_username@my_local_server
# asks for my_username password
cd /path/to/particular/folder
su particular_user_on_local_server
# asks for particular_user_on_local_server password
```

And then I can do my tasks (run some Ruby script on Rails applications, copy/remove files, restart services, etc.)

**I am trying to find a way to do this in a one-step script/command:**

> "`ssh` connect then `cd` to directory then `su` to this user"

I tried to use the following:

```
ssh username@server 'cd /some/path/to/folder ; su other_user'
# => does not keep my connection open to the server, just execute my `cd` 
#   and then tells me `su: must be run from terminal`
ssh username@server 'cd /some/path/to/folder ; bash ; su other_user'
# => keeps my connection open to the server but doesn't switch to user
#    and I don't see the usual `username:~/current/folder` prefix in the CLI
```

Is there a way to open a terminal (keep connection) on a remote server via `ssh` and change directory + switch to particular in a automated way? (to make things harder, I'm using Yakuake)

Comment: Is there a reason why you would `cd` before you `su`? The alternative would be easier since `su` without option may change the current directory.

Comment: that is a very good point @Aaron, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force allocation of a pseudo-terminal with `-t`, change to the desired directory and then replace the shell with one where you are the desired user:

```
ssh -t username@server 'cd /some/path/to/folder && exec bash -c "su other_user"'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I am trying to improve my script, now I am prompting the target directory (to append after the path `cd` is using, if present). But if I enter a directory that does not exists at this location, the whole connection is stopped. Is there a way to stay connected after the `cd` failed because "no such file or directory" error?

Comment: That's because of the `&&`. If you want to ignore the exit status of the `cd` command, you can replace `&&` by `;` and you'll get an error message about the non-existing directory, but `bash -c` will be executed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo -H` keeps the current working directory, so you could do:

```
ssh -t login_user@host.com 'cd /path/to/dir/; sudo -H -u other_user bash'
```

The `-t` parameter of `ssh` is needed otherwise the second sudo won't be able to ask you for your password.